# Problems with html/php Form to JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I realize I should probably be using angular for this, but I can't do that for this project.

What I am trying to do, is easily turn a form into an javascript object, which will be passed via AJAX.

The php script should then simply handle the object and do what I need with it.

The problem is, that my object is malformed.

So a form with fields like this:

```
<input type="text" name="chart_data[1][value]" />
```

But for whatever reason, my object looks like this!

```
chart_data[1: Object
color: "#726d86"
highlight: "#4f4868"
label: "Transportation"
value: "10"
```

The closing bracket is missing!  chart_data[1

I've tried two different functions to try and turn my data into an object.  Both seem to create the same problem.

Javascript is still my weakest language so any help would be appreciated!

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);

/*!
 * jQuery serializeObject - v0.2 - 1/20/2010
 * http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 "Cowboy" Ben Alman
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://benalman.com/about/license/
 */

// Whereas .serializeArray() serializes a form into an array, .serializeObject()
// serializes a form into an (arguably more useful) object.

(function($,undefined){
    '$:nomunge'; // Used by YUI compressor.

    $.fn.serializeObject = function(){
        var obj = {};

        $.each( this.serializeArray(), function(i,o){
            var n = o.name,
                v = o.value;

            obj[n] = obj[n] === undefined ? v
                : $.isArray( obj[n] ) ? obj[n].concat( v )
                : [ obj[n], v ];
        });

        return obj;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `.serialize()`?

Comment: I was under the impression that serialize would not handle 3d arrays too well, and also only be useful for $_GET requests

Comment: Serialize is supposed to generate the same parameters that would be sent if you submitted the form normally. And the same format is used for both `GET` and `POST` requests.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to do any of this. jQuery's built in `serialize()` will handle it for you

```
$('#formID').on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(resp){
      // do something with response
   }[,dataType])
});
```

Then in php the array represented by the `input` in question would be available using:

```
$chartDataArray = $_POST['chart_data'];
```